# Desktop Bridge app got an error code when request update: 0x769e4192

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

The following is the code I refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates#download-and-install-package-updates-with-the-users-permission) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#desktop). btnRequestUpdate_Click can be executed and can correctly ask me if I need to download the update, when I click "OK", I will get an error: "**0x769e4192 (located in appName.exe) exception: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error, located in memory location 0x06a8f0a0**"

I tried to use RequestDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync, but got the same error.

So how can I solve this problem? thanks a lot.

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("3E68D4BD-7135-4D10-8018-9FB6D9F33FA1")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IInitializeWithWindow
{
    void Initialize(IntPtr hwnd);
}

private async void btnRequestUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
    IInitializeWithWindow initWindow = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)context;
    initWindow.Initialize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);

    IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> storePackageUpdates =
        await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();
    if (storePackageUpdates.Count == 0) return;
    IAsyncOperationWithProgress<StorePackageUpdateResult, StorePackageUpdateStatus> downloadOperation =
        context.RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync(storePackageUpdates);
    downloadOperation.Progress = (asyncInfo, progress) =>
    {
        Consolo.WriteLine($"progress: {progress}");
    };
}
```

Comment: So, your app has published to store right?

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.requestdownloadstorepackageupdatesasync?view=winrt-18362). `RequestDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync` method will displays a UI dialog, it need to be called in  on the UI thread.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for your reply.  
The app has been published to the store, and I also make sure that this method is running on the UI thread. 
At the same time, the code can displays a UI dialog, but the problem is that when I click "OK", I will get an error.

Comment: uh, I have no environment for testing this issue, could you mind share a mini sample for us?

Comment: Please don't share sensitive info here.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. But what can I do to get you to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I suggest you open a support ticket [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) for this issue. And there is specific engineer help to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I did not purchase any support plan.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the entrance. Is that the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection)? The support plan seems to be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what problems I have encountered before. The key is to distinguish between "packaged version (released version)" and "unpackaged version (debug version)". I cannot upgrade to "packaged version" from "unpackaged version". So I try to release both the higher version and the lower version of the app to the store, and then I can upgrade to the higher version through the lower version.

In addition, using "package flights" to test the upgrade is much faster than using "submissions", because the "package flights" audit usually takes only half an hour.